# text area table format

Tags: java, textarea

Im trying to make a table like format using a Test Area for Java, and its not work correctly as it wont be in line...
But i need it to be in the correct format.
This is what i currently have

```
textArea.setText("Name\t\tAge\tDe-Sexed\tFee\n");

textArea.append("Text");
textArea.append("\t\t25");
textArea.append("\tYes");
textArea.append("\t\t$00.00\n");

textArea.append("sfessfesf");
textArea.append("\t\t12");
textArea.append("\tFalse");
textArea.append("\t\t$00.00\n");
```

So the output isnt very good with the third line of the output

any idea?

Comment: As camickr explained below a monospaces font is by definition a font where the letters each use the same width. If you do not use a monospaced font then certain letters such as w will be wider than the letter i for example this is just the way the letter images were created.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Monospaced Font for the JTextArea. Something like:

```
textArea.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12) );
```

Comment: I already have this, but i need the whole section to be the same width, if you get my meaning.

Comment: `i need the whole section to be the same width, if you get my meaning` - not sure I understand, but if I don't then the easiest way is to use a JTable, instead of a JTextArea. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.